# Difference in opening a file in Python in Linux versus Windows

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, python

What are the differences, if any, in how Python deals with opening/closing a file in Windows versus doing the same in Linux? I understand that in Linux the kernel acts as an interface between the software and the data stored in a hardware block device. Does Windows primarily do the same thing, or is there something under the hood that Python does to ensure the information is interpreted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the `CreateFile` API call is used to open or create a file. This returns a file handle, which is analogous to a file descriptor on Linux. From that perspective, it works more or less the same way.

On the other hand, as a Python programmer you have to be aware that Python does do some things differently that is not related to the low-level implementation. For example, on Linux opening the file in binary mode works the same way as text mode, but on Windows, where everything expects CRLF line endings, if you open the file in text mode, Python silently converts your `\n` to `\r\n`. This is obviously a bad thing if you are actually writing binary data. This is all quite well documented, though, so you don't need to worry about  kernel-level details.